# How to make or find a wall plug cover for mismatched double plugs

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I have 2 pairs of wall plugs (as depicted in the first image) that have different profiles. Most of the double pairs of plugs in the house look like the ones in the 2nd image and can fit the standard wall plug covers that are easy to find online. I haven't been able to find anything online that would fit the plugs in the first image.

I bought a double plug wall cover like in the second image and tried a couple of things to modify it to make it work on the mismatched plugs. I tried using both a hacksaw and a heated pyrography knife to cut out half of the cover so it would fit over the left rectangular plug. I did this twice with 2 covers and both times I failed. The plastic of these covers was just too hard and brittle and no matter how gentle I was it cracked at the end and the saw and heated knife could not get through it.

What ideas do you have to get a cover over these plugs?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You got a Dremel? You might get away modifying the type you have with that.

Comment: Those are called outlets, sockets or receptacles, but definitely not plugs. A plug is what you stick into one of these.

Comment: Do you have two socket points in the house that look like this? Jiggle them around so you have a pair of square and a pair of circular

Comment: One wonders why the original installer cut the ears off the yokes both top & bottom. There was no need since they should have been sitting nicely against the plastic old-work box. It's certainly _not_ a problem, just wasted effort...

Comment: @FreeMan Presumably it wasn't the original installer since they were present when the wall was painted grey... someone chopped them afterwards.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

### What you want is a decorator/duplex combination wall plate

What you're after is a 2-gang wall plate with a decorator (Decora) opening on the left and a standard duplex opening on the right, like so:

[image: 2 gang decorator/duplex combination wall plate]

You should have no trouble finding one of these at the local big-box store.

Comment: But what if the GFCI outlet was on the right????  (Oh, ... wait ...)

Comment: It might be worth noting that companies also sell modular systems that allow any combination of holes to be assembled in any desired order.  Such systems tend to be more expensive than single-piece plates in stock configurations, but can accommodate any arbitrary combination of device fronts.

Comment: @davidbak then you'll need a left-handed screwdriver to finish the job.

Comment: @davidbak sawzall the wall out an equal distance above/below the socket, then flip the whole chunk of wall over so it's in the room on the other side of the wall :)

Comment: I changed this to the accepted answer because the answer is not a clue in the comments like the other answer and being marked as such will hopefully direct future travelers to this question to the right place.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to just stick [a decora adapter plate](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001JEPX9Y) in front of the standard receptacle and buy a [double decora wall plate](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001JEPX94). This is a much more expensive route than Three-Phase's answer, but it would solve the problem and potentially make things look uniform.

Alternatively you could buy a decora receptacle and go double decora as well.

Comment: The adapter is creative, but for $6 you might as well just buy a decent grade decora receptacle instead.